# Checkboxes are not saved in the txt file

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have purchased a template from a well-known website. I have tweaked the lay-out of the template to my needs. But I can't figure out how to code the checkboxes in PHP to save them - when someone clicks on submit- in a txt file thats is located on my server. 
It saves the name and e-mail adress to the txt file but not the checkboxes. I have been searching for two days on the net to find some usefull tutorial. I found a basic php tutorial how to set up the checkboxes in php. I do not even know if I have set these checkboxes in php properly: see php section ''checkbox1'' and ''checkbox2''

HTML:

```
         <div>
            <label for="newsletter1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="input-check" id="newsletter1" name="newsletter1" value="huurder">
            <span style="width:120px;margin-top:30px;display:inline-block;clear">Ik ben een huurder</span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="input-check" id="newsletter2" name="newsletter2" value="verhuurder">
            <span style="width:120px;margin-top:30px;display:inline-block;">Ik ben een verhuurder</span>
          </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php          
        function response($responseStatus, $responseMsg) {
        $out = json_encode(array('responseStatus' => $responseStatus, 'responseMsg' => $responseMsg));

        ob_end_clean();
        die($out);
      }

      // only AJAX calls allowed
      if (!isset($_SERVER['X-Requested-With']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
        response('err', 'ajax');
      }

      // can't read/write to emails file?
      if (($file = fopen($emailsFile, 'r+')) == false) {
        response('err', 'fileopen');
      }

      // invalid name?
      if(!isset($_POST['newsletter-name'])
         || !trim($_POST['newsletter-name'])
         || strtolower($_POST['newsletter-name']) == 'name'
         || strlen($_POST['newsletter-name']) < 3) {
        response('err', 'name');
      }

      // invalid email address?
      if(!isset($_POST['newsletter-email']) || !preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', trim($_POST['newsletter-email']))) {
        response('err', 'email');
      }

      // checkbox1
      if(isset($_POST['newsletter1']) &&
       $_POST['newsletter1'] == 'huurder')
    {
        echo "Maak a.u.b. een keuze tussen huurder of verhuurder. Beiden opties zijn mogelijk.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ik ben geen huurder.";
    }    

        // checkbox1
    if(isset($_POST['newsletter2']) &&
       $_POST['newsletter2'] == 'verhuurder')
    {
        echo "Maak a.u.b. een keuze tussen huurder of verhuurder. Beiden opties zijn mogelijk.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ik ben een verhuurder.";
    }    

      // duplicate entry
      $name = trim(ucfirst($_POST['newsletter-name']));
      $emailAddress = trim(strtolower($_POST['newsletter-email']));
      while($line = fgets($file)) {
        $line = explode(' ', trim($line));
        $email = $line[0];
        if ($email == $emailAddress) {
          response('err', 'duplicate');
        }
      } // while

      // write email to file
      fseek($file, 0, SEEK_END);
      if (fwrite($file, $emailAddress . ' - ' . $name . PHP_EOL) == strlen($emailAddress . ' - ' . $name . PHP_EOL)) {
        // send email to site owner with new subscrciber info
        if (preg_match('/^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/', trim($myEmail))) {
            $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 \n";
            $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP " . PHP_VERSION . "\n";
            $headers .= "From: {$myEmail} \n";
            $headers .= "Return-Path: {$myEmail} \n";
            $message = 'The following person was kind enough to subscribe to your newsletter:' . PHP_EOL . $name . ' - ' . $emailAddress;
            @mail($myEmail, 'You have a new newsletter subscriber', $message, $headers);
        }
        response('ok', 'subscribed');
      } else {
        response('err', 'filewrite');
      }

      response('err', 'undefined');



    ?>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I found a basic php tutorial how to set up the checkboxes in php. I do not even know if I have set these checkboxes in php properly: see php section ''checkbox1'' and ''checkbox2''

Comment: In your code (HTML) you're using the name "newsletter1" twice. This might be the issue.

Comment: Done that but it still won't save the checkboxes to the txt file on my server. It saves the name and the e-mail adress of someone fine.

The name and e-mail adress are saved like this in the txt file:
Name - Email adress

What I want to achieve is the following:
Name - Email adress - Checkbox 1 or/and Checkbox 2

Comment: Ignore the fact that they are checkboxes, they're just strings stored in variables. Add the strings to the line with string concatenation.`echo 'Hello '.'World!';`

Comment: you arent using `$_POST['newsletter1']`, or `$_POST['newsletter2']` anywhere except to check they exist and are are set, you dont use them in any saving method.

Comment: also variable names cant use dashes

Comment: @PatrickEvans does it matter where you put the two codes in the php file. 

 $_POST['newsletter1']{
 }
 $_POST['newsletter2']{
 }

is this oke?

Comment: @KevinB
Thnx for the reply can you give more details of your method?

Comment: My method? its just string concatenation. I've already given you an example of how to do it.

Comment: @user1943906, if you do not understand basic string concatenation or where to even use your variables then you need more help than we can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter[]" value="huurder" />huurder<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter[]" value="verhuurder" />verhuurder<br />
```

And then access it in your php file like this:

```
 $newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];
  if(empty($newsletter)) 
  {
    echo("You didn't select any newsletter.");
  } 
  else
  {
    $N = count($newsletter);

    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
      echo($newsletter[$i] . " ");
      //save to variables and then write to file...
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will try it now. I hope this works its driving me crazy the last two days and this is very important element of the website, thnx for the effort.

Comment: It wont work when I click on submit it does nothing.
I have put your code above/
// duplicate entry in the php file 
maybe I put it wrong in the PHP where it not suppose to be.

Comment: The submit button is working, but it wont save the value of the checkboxes in the txt file.